# How can I make this sentence more parallel in structure? (Example below)

Tags: parallelism

> In particular, the consumption of water allows chemical reactions **to take place**, substances to be readily transported, body temperature to be regulated, and tissues to be protected and lubricated in the body.

I noticed that the three remaining points used to be + past tense of verb whereas the first one didn't really followed that structure...

Please feel free to rephrase the entire sentence too! Depending on what would be the best way to phrase it :D

Comment: Looks parallel enough for me. A little passive, but clear. Maybe *the body* is the agent in all cases, and you could turn the verbs around to reflect that.

Comment: There is an adverbial in the end (in the body) which is not connected to anything in particular, which is rather dangling. Is it "and tissues in the body to be protected and lubricated "?

Comment: @LPH What adverbial are you talking about? It is perfectly clear at once that *consumption of water* leads to all the things that follow. The last one in the series (preceded by Oxford Comma) happens to be *protection and lubrication of tissues*. And I concur with Yosef Baskin that the sentence is parallel enough.

Comment: @user405662 Don't you call "in the body" an adverbial?

Comment: If you just need a **passive infinitive** to make the first item parallel to the others' passive infinitives, try: _allows chemical reactions **to be initiated**_. Or you can make the whole thing active voice: *In particular, the consumption of water allows the body to initiate chemical reactions, transport substances, regulate body temperature, and protect and lubricate tissues.*

Comment: **Please write answers. Comments may be removed without warning.**

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a [**passive infinitive**](https://www.thoughtco.com/passive-infinitive-grammar-1691488) to make the first item parallel to the others' passive infinitives (*to be readily transported*, *to be regulated*, *to be protected and lubricated*), try:

> *allows chemical reactions **to be initiated***

Or you can make the whole thing active voice:

> *In particular, the consumption of water allows the body to initiate chemical reactions, transport substances, regulate body temperature,
> and protect and lubricate tissues.*